# Connect to websocket using https request

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, https, connection

I'm trying to make a websocket server on node.js, but my hosting services only allow http so I cannot connect directly to websockets. That's why I wanted to establish a websocket connection from the http request. Is there any way to do that?
My server's code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: true
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }
    
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
        else if (message.type === 'binary') {
            console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
            connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
        }
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you asking about https when you say your hosting services don't allow https?  I'm confused.  To connect to a webSocket using https, you NEED an https server.

Comment: It ALLOWS https:// but not wss://

Comment: A websocket connection always starts with an http/https connection.  wss:// is not really a protocol, that's just a shortcut used on the client.  All websocket connections start with an http or https connection.   You need to discuss this with your hosting provider, not with us.  Nothing we can do.  As far as your code is concerned, you create an https server and hook your webSocket server-side object to it.  Right now, you show hooking your websocket object it to an http server, so of course it won't be https.